# Adding new element to page with PHP

Tags: php

I'm setting up a registration page, and I'm adding checks right now for forms that are left empty.

Here's the HTML I have for the username form:

```
<label>Username</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
</div>
```

And the PHP I have:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

if(empty($username)) {
  // todo
}
```

What I need for the "**todo**" portion of the PHP to do is to add a new line under the input form in the HTML, like this:

```
<label>Username</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
  <div class="form-warning">This username is already taken!</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed your PHP directly inot the HTML if you use the `<?php` and `?>` tags:

```
<label>Username</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
<?php
  if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
      echo '<div class="form-warning">This username is already taken!</div>';
  }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for single quotes and actually checking `$_POST['username']`

Comment: What if I wanted all of the PHP in a separate file since I'm handling the form there?

Comment: When I try this code, it shows the form-warning class even without typing anything into the form (it's there by default). What's wrong?

Comment: @ErikFischer You can't emit an HTML file and have a completely separate PHP file modify it after the event. You could use a PHP file to read your HTML and modify it on the fly, but that's complex and prone to error. You might be able to do what you seem to want with Javascript, but that's a different question.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, and found out it wasn't efficient.

But, when I try your code, it shows the form-warning class even without typing anything into the form (it's there by default). What's wrong?

Comment: @ErikFischer Is your form actually submitting a value called 'username'? Watch the spelling (case is significant), and make sure you're using a POST request. The code assumes that your form processing is going on in the same file as the form production. If you just output the code as is in a raw form, then yes, it will display that message.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

if(empty($username)) {
  echo "<div class=\"form-warning\">This username is already taken!</div>";
}
```

Comment: Why not use single quotes for the string? Then you wouldn't have to escape the double quotes around your HTML attributes. Also, you have an unchecked array index

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below.

```
<label>Username</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
   <?php echo $errorDiv;  ?>
</div>
```

and for PHP check.

```
$errorDiv = "";
if(empty($username)) {
  $errorDiv = "<div class=\"form-warning\">This username is already taken!</div>";
}
```

Comment: place `$errorDiv` at the start of the page and replace blank value with `error div html` code and there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

There are options given. Another way might be adding variables to your html as a class name.

CSS:

```
.show_warning {
   display: block;
}

.hide_warning {
   display: none;
}
```

PHP:

```
    if(empty($username)){
      $username_warning = "show_warning";
    } else {
    $username_warning = "hide_warning";
   }
```

HTML + PHP

```
<label>Username</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
  <div class="form-warning <?php echo $username_warning;?>">This username is already taken!</div>
</div>
```

If the $username is empty, you add the class "show_warning". You can easily add this class to other variables and integrate them with other fields.

PHP:

```
if(empty($phonenumber))
  $phone_warning = "show_warning";
else
  $phone_warning = "hide_warning";
```

Answer (score -1):

try this dude:

```
<?php

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  ?>
  <label>Username</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST) && empty($username)) {
    <div class="form-warning">This username is already taken!</div>
  }
?>
</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use Ajax check....

if you are using jQuery, then use this js

```
<label>Username</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="username" maxlength="25" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
  <div class="form-warning">This username is already taken!</div>
</div>

<scrip type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(input[name=username]).change(function(){
         $.post(
               'your-sever-process-link',
               { username : $(this).val()},
               function(res) : { $(this).parent().childrens('.form-warning').html(res.message) },
               'json' 
          );
   });
});
</script>
```

Assuming your server processing script will check for deuplicates and sends json encoded value.

Also ajax validation processing makes a better UX. You can use https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine . Its easy an good.